# Multiplying a matrix by a certain unitary matrix: effect on the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-analysis

Is there any quick way to conclude on the eigenvalues of $T = U S$ ? Can we express them with respect to the eigenvalues of $S$, $\lambda( S)$. 
Where:

$$S = S^T $$
($S$ is symmetric)
$$ U = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \ldots &  &   &  & \ldots & 0     \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & \ldots & 0   \\
0 & & \ddots & 0 & 0 &  0 & \ldots  & 0   \\
0 &  & \ldots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & & \ldots & 0 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & & \ldots & 0 & 0 & -1 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 &  & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & &  \ldots &  &  &  & \ldots & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
($U$ is unitary and diagonal.Half top rows are negative the rows of an identity matrix, half bottom are exactly the rows of an identity matrix)

Comment: No, unless $S$ is already of the form $\begin{pmatrix}S_1\\&S_2\end{pmatrix}$ (same block size as $U=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&-1\end{pmatrix}$) for example.

Comment: it is  a matrix of the form $S = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{pmatrix}$